# EXCEL Formula not auto updating! Help!

Tags: excel

I have an excel formula to pull the name of the file in excel and put it into a field. The problem is, when I open multiple files I've already done, it repulls the file name and updates it to the LAST file opened. So if I opened MFULTON and then JADAM, the file name cell for JADAM would real MFULTON. If I manually double click and press enter, it will auto correct back to JADAM, but my colleagues won't know how to do this. What is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Uou need to make your formula Volatile

Comment: For a definition of Volatile: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213653(office.11).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Go to `File->options->Formulas-> Workbook Calculation-> Select Automatic.` And also Check the check box `Formula Auto Complete.`