# Excel LOOKUP Function not updating

Tags: excel, pivot-table, formula, lookup

Got a pivot table I'm updating every day (new values column N). From inside pivot table I'm trying to pick the last value, using this formula:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(N:N<>""),N:N)
```

Formula works, but it wont update when a new value/day is entered into the pivot table. To do this I have to enter the cell holding my formua, and press enter. Then it updates.
Why wont my formula update?

Comment: Check if Workbook Calculation in Excel Options>Formulas is Automatic. If set to manual it will not be automatic and you will have to calculate/refresh it each time .. See this .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432657/excel-formula-not-auto-updating-help ... and .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43892404/excel-formula-not-updating

Comment: That was an easy fix. :) Thanks a lot for helping out.